# why different result from mac and linux?

Tags: c++, linux

When I compile the following code in Mac, it output 'correct'; But when compile it with g++ (Red Hat 4.4.7-16), it output 'error'. That is to say malloc fail to new memory. Why and how to solve it?

```
typedef struct NODE_t{
     uint32_t pos;
     char refChar;
     char targetChar;
}*NODE;
int main() {
    uint64_t sub_size = 51086559504ll;
    NODE nodes = (NODE) malloc(sub_size);
    if (NULL == nodes) {
        printf("error");
    } else {
        printf("correct\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to allocate so much memory? There's no "fix" for this, your system doesn't have enough memory to back up your `malloc` request.

Comment: Unless you have more than 52GB of RAM installed, neither of the results is surprising. gcc can't get the RAM and clang probably did not even try to and just optimized the whole program to `printf("correct\n");`.

Comment: If this is C++ then there's a lot of things wrong with it (using `malloc`, C style casts, using `NULL` instead of `nullptr`, `typedef`ing a `struct`)

Comment: @UnholySheep That's not _wrong_, it's just unidiomatic.

Comment: @UnholySheep Nothing about that is explicitly wrong.

Comment: you need to handle the result of malloc http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html

Comment: It looks like you want to allocate ~52 GB of RAM. Do you have that much on both systems?

Comment: @BaummitAugen, that's 51GB. You don't need 51GB of _physical_ RAM installed to satisfy that request.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis yeah not physically but you even need to have swap configured on both system enough. The difference can just be a system configuration.

Comment: also seeing that your g++ is kind of old. Is you redhat 64 bit?

Comment: @Hayt I think both system do not have so big RAM.

Comment: @Hayt  yes, Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7 (64bit).

Comment: @GillBates This is other guy's code. I need his results. So terrible.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis *"that's 51GB"* It's more than that, and you need some RAM for the rest of your system. *"You don't need 51GB of physical RAM installed to satisfy that request."* Can you really have a single contiguous allocation that can never get loaded to RAM, i.e. lives and can be used only directly in the swap space? Or can you load that chunk by chunk?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Actually, it is **~47,578 GB**. And `malloc` doesn't need a contiguous *physical* allocation and can allocate blocks much larger than the RAM size, it only needs enough *virtual* memory. The problem here is the system does not support or is not configured for that much virtual memory.

Comment: @AndréSassi You are confusing Gigabytes (ca. 51.09 GB) and Gibibytes (ca. 47.58 GiB).

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because sub_size is too large a value for the Red Hat implementation of malloc().  Basically you are requesting more bytes than there are available.  It could be that you have less memory in the Linux machine, or there could be some limit within the code that is preventing it working as you expect.

Comment: Yes. The code is a part of other software. I need to re-run it. But always run time error. Finally, I find that the code fail to new memory.